# ASP API CORE : Get relation Many to One

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have two entities : Article and PrixVariation.
One Article has Many Prix variation.
One Prix variation has One Article.

```
public partial class Article
            {
                public Article()
                {            
                    PrixVariations = new HashSet<PrixVariation>();
                }
        
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }         
    ... 
                public virtual ICollection<PrixVariation> PrixVariations { get; set; }
    
            }
public partial class PrixVariation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public int Article { get; set; }
        public double Prix { get; set; }

        public virtual Article ArticleNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    }
```

My Context is as follow :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Article>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("articles");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

                
                entity.Property(e => e.DateTime)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("dateTime")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                
            });

 modelBuilder.Entity<PrixVariation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("prix_variation");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasColumnName("id");

                entity.Property(e => e.Article).HasColumnName("article");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateTime)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("dateTime")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Prix).HasColumnName("prix");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.ArticleNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PrixVariations)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Article)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_prix_variation_articles");
            });
```

And my controller is as follow :

```
public class ArticlesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly STGEORGESContext _context;

        public ArticlesController(STGEORGESContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Articles
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Article>>> GetArticles()
        {
            return await _context.Articles.ToListAsync();
        }
....
```

There is something not working here because when I launch the debogger, the collection of PrixVaration is always empty :

```
{"id":1,"dateTime":"2021-11-28T08:37:17","prixVariations":[]}
```

And of course in the database there is one PrixVaration linked to that Article..

Can anyone can help ?? Thaks a lot !!!

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called  lazy loading. Ef doesn't load any object collections if you don't ask about it explicitly. So try this

```
return await _context.Articles.Include(i=> i.PrixVariations).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Serge,
Thank you sooooo much, you put me on the right track.. I am just having problem with error "A possible object cycle was detected ... Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles".. I am trying to find how to set this up in ASP API..

Comment: @123pierre You are welcome. Check this link and let me know if it helps you https://gavilan.blog/2021/05/19/fixing-the-error-a-possible-object-cycle-was-detected-in-different-versions-of-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks again Serge! I wish I had your knowledge :-)
For people reading us in future : In ASP API Core :
Program.cs, add the line :
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

Comment: @123pierre Thank you for feed back. I am glad that it is working